# Ayuda con este error: Failed to load plugin url: https://degranero.es/wp-content/plugins/easy-columns/tinymce/langs/es.js

Tags: plugins

Al actualizar a wordpress 5.5.1 sale ese error: Failed to load plugin url: https://degranero.es/wp-content/plugins/easy-columns/tinymce/langs/es.js

No puedo editar mi web. ¿Qué tengo que hacer?

Comment: Hi - could you translate your question please? Or there's [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) if you'd rather try there.

Comment: I'd be surprised if the upgrade caused this though. Can you check for an update to the Easy Columns plugin? Or you could try and find a copy of the tinymce es.js, or make a copy of another language as es.js in that folder, or temporarily change your admin site language to English?